# NZ to USA do we collect luggage at Hawaii transit stop?

Tags: transit, hawaii

We're looking at flights from NZ to San Diego in October.  One of the options has a 3.5 hours stop in Hawaii (I suspect also change of planes) before flying to on San Diego.

Do we collect and re-check our luggage in Hawaii for the flight to San Diego?

Both flights are Hawaiian Airlines, although the website I'm looking at lists the two flights from different terminals (Arrive Terminal I, depart Terminal Z)

Comment: Yes, definitely change of planes. When you book a multi-leg trip on an airline with a layover _at that airline's main hub_ you can always expect to change planes there. It might be, through exceptional coincidence, that the outbound leg is flown by the same physical aircraft as the inbound one, but you wouldn't even be able to tell that except by paying _really_ careful attention to the tail number of the aircraft as you board it.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes, since Honolulu is your first stop in the United States, that is where you need to collect your luggage, carry it through customs, and re-drop it for your onward flight.

That's how it works for all international arrivals to any U.S. airport.

The flight from Honolulu to San Diego is U.S. domestic.