# How do I efficiently handle my bags during a long layover in Honolulu?

Tags: usa, air-travel, customs-and-immigration, luggage, airports

I am a US citizen. I will be flying from California to New Zealand and back in March 2018. The return leg has a long layover in Honolulu: arrive at 6am, depart at 9pm. All tickets were booked via Air New Zealand, but the Honolulu to California leg is “operated by United”.

I don’t want to spend all that time in the airport when I could see the city instead. But I’m not sure about practicalities. My understanding from [this earlier question](https://travel.stackexchange.com/q/66776) is that I will need to clear customs and immigration in Honolulu. So my question is, will I need to keep my bags with me all day in Honolulu, or can I drop them off with United at the airport? It would make navigating the city quite tough if I can’t leave my bags at the airport.

Comment: Which direction are you asking about? On the way to NZ, you _don’t_ need to clear customs as you are still in the USA; your bags will be checked through. On the way to CA, you are _entering the USA_ in Honolulu, and have to carry your bags through customs. Normally, you drop them right off after the customs officer, to an airline attendee; but I haven’t tried this specifically in Honolulu.

Comment: I’m asking specifically about the return leg, as the question says.

Comment: Ok. I read it three times, and missed that piece three time... sorry.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will have to retrieve your bags after clearing customs. [United typically won't take bags for a flight that is more than 4 hours from departure](https://www.united.com/web/en-US/content/travel/airport/process/default.aspx). There are some luggage storage options available, [listed here](http://hidot.hawaii.gov/airports/faqs/). The cheapest one will cost $20 for up to 4 bags. The bags are stored off site but will be picked up and returned to you at the airport. They operate from 8 AM to 8 PM, so you may have to wait at the airport for a little while after your flight lands and make sure you're back at the airport in time to collect your bags.

Comment: Before security got so picky (without actually improving much), you could just rent a locker for a quarter.  Now you can take your bag (no matter how dangerous its contents) to a consignment desk and pay a higher sum to have it stuck in a closet _unexamined_ with a lot of others.  And if it explodes, your fingerprints won't be on the closet door.

Comment: Given that it's a direct connection, are you certain that the 4-hour limit would apply?

Comment: @phoog: I can't say for certain, but I wouldn't expect them to and wouldn't count on them doing it. It could be worth a shot to try since OP will have to wait 1-2 hours for the luggage storage to open anyway.

Comment: United checked my bags through in Frankfurt for a nine hour layover. So the four hour limit probably applies only to initial check-ins.